# How to link Kaminari Gem to a locale file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

I'm trying to link my Kaminari gem to a local file: `config/locales/kaminari-fr.yml` in order to translate the pagination text in French.

How should I specify to Kaminary to look for the translations in this file ?

Comment: You don't have to configure anything for this. `config/locales/kaminari-fr.yml` file should contain data accordingly. What errors are you getting after placing this file ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do not get any error, the translation is just not considered.

Comment: Here is how config/locales/kaminari-fr.yml is looking : `fr:
  views:
    pagination:
      first: "&laquo; Première"
      last: "Dernière &raquo;"
      previous: "&lsaquo; Précédente"
      next: "Suivante &rsaquo;"
      truncate: "&hellip;"
  helpers:
    page_entries_info:
      one_page:
        display_entries:
          zero: "Aucun(e) %{entry_name} trouvé(e)s"
          one: "Affichage de <b>1</b> %{entry_name}"
          other: "Affichage des <b>%{count}</b> %{entry_name}"`

Comment: Have you made `fr` locale available in the app ? `config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :fr]` => `application.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure `fr` locale available in the application.

Add this line:

```
# file => config/application.rb
config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :fr]
```

You can set locale on each request based on user's locale from controller.

```
I18n.locale = current_user.locale
```

OR

```
I18n.locale = :fr # Explicitly french locale
```

Now french locale content should be fetched and displayed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. But then how to make Kaminari understand that he should go after to `config/locales/kaminari-fr.yml` ?

Comment: Rails autoloads every locale file in config/locales directory.